# Javascript - Jump to anchor function

Tags: javascript, anchor

I use this script to check if an anchor is within the URL. If found the *showscroll* function get called. 
Only thing isn't working is the jump to the called anchor. 
I'm new to JS - what is wrong with the function?

In the HTML page:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    function checkurl(){
    if (window.location.href.match(/\#more/))
    {
    showscroll('more');
    }
    if (window.location.href.match(/\#tab2/))
    {
    showscroll('tab2');
    }

    }
    //-->
    </script>

    </head>                   

    <body onload="checkurl()">
```

.JS

```
function showscroll(id){
    if (document.getElementById) {
    var divid = document.getElementById(id);
    divid.style.display = divid.style.display='block';
    // NOT WORKING:
 window.location.href = "#"+id;
//
    return false;
} }
```

Edit: I can't use "scroll into view".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

> ```
> window.location.href.match(/\#more/)
> ```

you can just do

```
window.location.hash == '#more'
```

and instead of assigning to the fragment, you can use the `scrollIntoView` method as described at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView

> **Summary**
>
> The `scrollIntoView()` method scrolls the element into view.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `element.scrollIntoView(alignWithTop);`
>
> `alignWithTop` Optional
>
> > If true, the scrolled element is aligned with the top of the scroll area. If false, it is aligned with the bottom.
> > Note: By default, the element is scrolled to align with the top of the scroll area.

Comment: Looks like "window.location.hash == '#more'" is a typo. Two equals "==" is a comparison operator. One equals "=" is assignment, and is correct.

Comment: @AnthonyScaife, I'm trying to compare.  `.match` does not do assignment.